# fast V representation update of polytope

Tags: convex-polytopes, computational-geometry, polyhedra

Say that I have both the V and the H representation of a (possibly unbounded) polytope $P$. I want to append a some rows to the H representation, how can I quickly update the V representation to incorporate the additional constraints?

I case it matters, the additional rows are just intersections with orthants, that is, restricting values to be of a particular sign.

Comment: The number of vertices could grow exponentially with the number of hyperplanes, no?

Comment: Yes, that's true. In fact, it is the essence of why it is important to have an updating formula. I'm hoping for some clean and simple specialization of something like the "Double Description Method" described at Lemma 9.1 here: https://inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/lect/pclect/notes2015/PolyComp2015.pdf